# Is there a timeout for acking RabbitMQ messages?

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

I would like to set a timeout after which a dequeued message is automatically NACKed.

When I dequeue a message I wait until it is transfered over a socket and the other party confirms its reception.

Do I need to keep a list of Timers or can RMQ handle this automatically?

```
private void Run()
{
    _rmqConnection = _queueConnectionFactory.CreateFactory().CreateConnection();

    _rmqReadchannel = _rmqConnection.CreateModel();

    _rmqReadchannel.QueueDeclare(QueueIdOutgoing(), true, false, false, null);

    _rmqReadchannel.BasicQos(0, 1, false);
    var consumer = new QueueingBasicConsumer(_rmqReadchannel);
    _rmqReadchannel.BasicConsume(QueueIdOutgoing(), false, consumer);
    while (true)
    {
        if (!_rmqReadchannel.IsOpen)
        {
            throw new Exception("Channel is closed");
        }
        var ea = consumer.Queue.Dequeue();
        string jsonData = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ea.Body);
        if (OnOutgoingMessageReady != null)
        {
            OnOutgoingMessageReady(this, new QueueDataEventArgs(jsonData, ea.DeliveryTag));
        }
        //waiting for ACK from a different thread
    }
}
```

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Yes. This is discussed in the [official Python tutorial](https://rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-python.html):

> A timeout (30 minutes by default) is enforced on consumer delivery acknowledgement. This helps detect buggy (stuck) consumers that never acknowledge deliveries.

You can find more information available on the RabbitMQ documentation for [Delivery Acknowledgement Timeout](https://www.rabbitmq.com/consumers.html#acknowledgement-timeout)

However, this was not always the case. Older versions of RabbitMQ (at least through version 3.6.x) did not provide any sort of timeout mechanism for acknowledging messages. This was mentioned in [older versions of the official Python tutorial](http://previous.rabbitmq.com/v3_6_x/tutorials/tutorial-two-python.html):

> There aren't any message timeouts; RabbitMQ will redeliver the message only when the worker connection dies. It's fine even if processing a message takes a very, very long time.

[Section 3.1.8 of the AMQP 0-9-1 specification](https://www.rabbitmq.com/resources/specs/amqp0-9-1.pdf) describes Acknowledgements, and is very clear that they can either be *Automatic* (the client doesn't have to do anything, messages are acknowledged as soon as they are delivered) or *Explicit* (the client must an Ack for each message or group of messages that it has processed).

Here's some [past discussion](http://rabbitmq.1065348.n5.nabble.com/adjusting-timeout-for-non-acked-messages-to-be-requeued-td10084.html) from back in 2009 confirming this behavior.

The first reference to changing this behavior that I can see is [this PR](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/pull/1972) from April 2019. I'm not sure what version of the server that change was included in, but it sounds like the default was initially "no timeout", then 15 minutes in [RabbitMQ 3.8.15](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/releases/tag/v3.8.15), then 30 minutes in [RabbitMQ 3.8.17](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/releases/tag/v3.8.17) (where it remains as of October 2021).

So: This behavior is dependent on your version of RabbitMQ. Older versions required you to explicitly send NACKs after some interval. Newer versions have a default timeout.

Comment: Without arguing against the validity of this answer (which was correct at the time of posting), newer versions of RabbitMQ since then have implemented "consumer ack timeout" (default is 30 min), and are enforcing it rigorously. Please refer to the @Egor's answer, above.

Comment: @leonidos79 Thanks for pointing that out; I've updated my answer to take into account both the current behavior and the fact that the default behavior has changed over time.

Answer (score 17):

Modern versions of RabbitMQ have [ack timeout](https://www.rabbitmq.com/consumers.html#acknowledgement-timeout).
So be careful with updates to new versions if you have consumers that spend a lot of time before delivery acknowledgement.

> If a consumer does not ack its delivery for more than the timeout value (30 minutes by default), its channel will be closed with a PRECONDITION_FAILED channel exception.

**UPD:**
Updated doc contains instruction for disabling timeout:

> The timeout can be deactivated using advanced.config. This is not recommended:

```
%% advanced.config
[
  {rabbit, [
    {consumer_timeout, undefined}
  ]}
].
```

> Instead of disabling the timeout entirely, consider using a high value (for example, a few hours).

Comment: thank you, so this is can be set to maximum? What is the max value?

Comment: @toha  I don't know what the max size of this property, rabbit docs don't have any info about it. But I have just noticed an update in rabbit docs that allows to deactivate all timeouts. I added it to my answer.

Comment: very good. I will try to make it for some hours. 
After trial I hope nothing happened again