# RabbitMQ Ack Timeout

Tags: rabbitmq

I'm using RPC Pattern for processing my objects with RabbitMQ.

You suspect,I have an object, and I want to have that process finishes and 
After that send ack to RPC Client.

Ack as default has a timeout about 3 Minutes.

My process Take long time.

How can I change this timeout for ack of each objects or what I must be do for handling these like processess?

Comment: Where have you find the "3 minutes timeout" ? I think there is no message timeout unless the connection broken.

Comment: Please edit your question better describing your issue. What client library are you using to connect to the broker? How do you implement the RPC pattern? Where is the default value set?

Comment: try here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30546977/is-there-a-timeout-for-acking-rabbitmq-messages

Comment: The issue you seem to be having is outside of RabbiMQ. Where is your code? This question should be closed as-is for lack of suitable detail.

Answer (score 64):

Modern versions of RabbitMQ have a [delivery acknowledgement timeout](https://www.rabbitmq.com/consumers.html#acknowledgement-timeout):

> In modern RabbitMQ versions, a timeout is enforced on consumer delivery acknowledgement. This helps detect buggy (stuck) consumers that never acknowledge deliveries. Such consumers can affect node's on disk data compaction and potentially drive nodes out of disk space.
>
> If a consumer does not ack its delivery for more than the timeout value (30 minutes by default), its channel will be closed with a PRECONDITION_FAILED channel exception. The error will be logged by the node that the consumer was connected to.

Error message will be:

> Channel error on connection <####> :
> operation none caused a channel exception precondition_failed: consumer ack timed out on channel 1

Timeout by default is 30 minutes (1,800,000ms)<sup>note 1</sup> and is configured by the `consumer_timeout` parameter in `rabbitmq.conf`.

---

<sup>note 1: Timeout was 15 minutes (900,000ms) [before RabbitMQ 3.8.17](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/releases/tag/v3.8.17).</sup>

Comment: This does not seem to work for me. I changed the consumer_timeout in rabbitmq.conf (etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf) stopped the app, reset, started the app and the timeout is not respected. I also can't find where the default value is. Any suggestions. Running RabbitMQ 3.8.16 in a docker container locally for testing purposes

Comment: @thecommoner The timeout config should be in /etc/rabbitmq/advanced.config

Comment: @oday-fraiwan your statement about advanced.config file is erroneous. You can view sample config file for rabbitMQ [here](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/blob/32d866916accab5bc8638ea592ff9eb1dba04d69/deps/rabbit/docs/rabbitmq.conf.example#L602)

Answer (score 3):

if you run rabbitmq in docker, you can describe volume with file rabbitmq.conf, then create this file inside volume and set consumer_timeout
for example:

docker compose

```
version: "2.4"
services:
  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3.9.13-management-alpine
    network_mode: host
    container_name: 'you name'
    ports:
        - 5672:5672
        - 15672:15672 ----- if you use gui for rabbit
    volumes:
        - /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf:/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf
```

And you need create file

> rabbitmq.conf

on you server by this way

> /etc/rabbitmq/

documentation with params: https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/blob/v3.8.x/deps/rabbit/docs/rabbitmq.conf.example