# How Masstransit deals with slow consumer

Tags: rabbitmq, masstransit

I am using Masstransit 7.0.0 with consumer to process the messages from RabbitMQ. I have observed when the consumer is slow processing the message or when I put the debug point in visual studio for consumer, after some time my consumer receives the message again. My assumption is Masstransit thought consumer crashed and sent the message again.

In my case, my consumer is some times slow processing the message as it talks to external endpoints but the processing is around 30-40 seconds and not minutes.

Could you please explain How masstransit knows the consumer is crashed( or whatever it is) to resend the message? If it waits for certain amount of time waiting for ack, then Is there setting anywhere just to increase this time little bit specific to queue/consumer?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With RabbitMQ, there is no timeout after which the message would be redelivered. If you are stopping the consumer in the debugger, you are likely causing the RabbitMQ socket connection to close. When the connection is closed, MassTransit will reconnect at which point any messages not previously acknowledged would be redelivered.

In normal operation, consumers that take 30, 60, 90, even 300 seconds are rarely an issue as the broker connection is maintained.

Comment: Hi Chris, Thanks for the reply. I don’t think debugger is closing the socket connection as I see the debugger hit second time when the message got redelivered. I only paused the execution with the debug but the app is live and running so I don’t see any reason for socket closing.. And also it is not one time issue and I can consistently do that

Comment: Well, again, the debugger stops all threads, sockets included. So, check the RMQ logs, and I'll bet you see a disconnect.

Comment: Hi Chris, I have checked the log file on RabbitMQ server while in visual studio debug mode and as you correctly pointed out there is a connection close event in the log file but it mentions heart beat timeout 60s. Does that mean after 60s rabbitmq redelivers the message if the consumer is passed or it is just my visual studio debugger causing all the problems? 
here is the log file [error] <0.9495.3> closing AMQP connection <0.9495.3> ([::1]:40670 -> [::1]:5672 - TestConsumer):missed heartbeats from client, timeout: 60s

Comment: It's your debugger, when you're waiting at a breakpoint, everything in the process stops - including socket I/O to backing services such as RabbitMQ. So the timeout is the handshake between RMQ and the RMQ client socket connection. If you aren't debugging, everything stays connected fine.

Comment: This answer is relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67581599/68432

In "modern" versions of Rabbit (we're on 3.9.6) there is a default timeout of 30 mins which caught us out.